# When the name of a router link is dynamic how should we name the link?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a list of items in navbar that will be rendered. Each item should have a link related to its name. Because I don't want to hard code the links I don't know how to name the links.

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown no-caret class="mr-2">
  <!-- Using 'button-content' slot -->
  <template #button-content>
    <div><b-icon icon="person-fill"></b-icon> {{ userItems[0] }}</div>
  </template>
  <b-dropdown-item
    v-for="(userItem, index) in userItems[1]"
    :key="index"
    :to="userItem"
  >
    {{ userItem }}
  </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

:to="{name: userItem }" doesn't work either.

Comment: is there any error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be:

```
<b-dropdown-item
  v-for="(userItem, index) in userItems[1]"
  :key="index"
>
  <router-link to="your_path_or_route_name_here">
</b-dropdown-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but since I had no idea about your data I created my own `userItems`. I created a code snippet for you to better understand the implementation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      userItems: [{
          name: "Link 1",
          path: "/link1"
        },
        {
          name: "Link 2",
          path: "/link2"
        },
        {
          name: "Link 3",
          path: "/link3"
        }

      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-nav-item-dropdown no-caret class="mr-2">
    <!-- Using 'button-content' slot -->
    <template #button-content>
      <div>
      Dropdown
      </div>
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="(userItem, index) in userItems" :key="index" :to="userItem.path">
      {{ userItem.name }}
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-nav-item-dropdown>
</div>
```